# No output from child Python executed with subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

This is a simple command that works from command line:

```
> python -c "print('asdasd')"
asdasd
```

But it fails to output anything when executed from the script:

```py
import os
import sys
import subprocess

cmd = [sys.executable] + ['-c', '"print(\'asdasd\')"']
print cmd
kwargs = {
  'stdout': subprocess.PIPE,
  'stderr': subprocess.PIPE,
  'stdin': subprocess.PIPE,
}

print subprocess.Popen(cmd).communicate()
print subprocess.Popen(cmd, **kwargs).communicate()
```

The output:

```
['C:\\Python27\\python.exe', '-c', '"print(\'asdasd\')"']
(None, None)
('', '')
```

Why it doesn't produce anything? I am out of ideas. Looks like a bug in Python 2.7.11 to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need those extra double-quotes for `'"print(\'asdasd\')"'` in your command line arguments. As it is, your code will just execute a python code that do the following: `"print(\'asdasd\')"`. In other word, it will produce the string: *print(\'asdasd\')*

Obviously, creating a string won't print anything. Here is a patched version of your code:

```py
import os
import sys
import subprocess

cmd = [sys.executable] + ['-c', 'print(\'asdasd\')']
print cmd
kwargs = {
    'stdout': subprocess.PIPE,
    'stderr': subprocess.PIPE,
    'stdin': subprocess.PIPE,
}

print subprocess.Popen(cmd).communicate()
print subprocess.Popen(cmd, **kwargs).communicate()
```

You may want to use the [shlex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html) module to parse your command line argument.

For example, using the shlex module and the triple quotes with a string format (do not forget quotes for the python path, otherwise characters such as backslash will be interpreted):

```py
import sys
import shlex
import subprocess

cmd_str = '''"{}" -c "print('asdasd')"'''.format(sys.executable)
print(cmd_str)
cmd = shlex.split(cmd_str)
print(cmd)
kwargs = {
    'stdout': subprocess.PIPE,
    'stderr': subprocess.PIPE,
    'stdin': subprocess.PIPE,
}
print(subprocess.Popen(cmd).communicate())
print(subprocess.Popen(cmd, **kwargs).communicate())
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew there is something obvious, but I thought it is somewhere in `subprocess`. I quoted the string, because it was quoted in raw command line, but when arguments are expressed in a list, Python quotes them itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
subprocess.Popen(['{} -c "print(\'ECHO\')"'.format(sys.executable)], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
```

Comment: @anatolytechtonik Edited, give it another try.